# Get query parameters in React, Typescript

Tags: typescript, reactjs

I have a component that looks like this:

```
class MyView extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    render() {
        console.log((this.props as any).params); // prints empty object
        return (
            <div>Sample</div>
        );
    }
}
```

I want to print the URL query params but I get an empty object.
(Yes, I know that I declared {} as Props but if I don't define it, it does not compile).

Is there a way to pass a "default" props object to my component so that I can access `this.props.params`? Or should it be done in a different way in TypeScript?

Comment: How do you render this component? Are you passing this `param` property to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the types for the props and state and then put them instead of the `{}`.
It's not clear where you want to get the "URL query params", so I'll just take them from the `window.location` object:

```
interface MyViewProperties {
    params: string;
}

interface MyViewState {}

class MyView extends React.Component<MyViewProperties, MyViewState> {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.params); // should print "param1=value1&param2=value2...."
        return (
            <div>Sample</div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyView props={ window.location.search.substring(1) } />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To assign default properties to a component you should use defaultProps:

```
class MyView extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    render() {
        console.log((this.props as any).params); // prints empty object
        return (
            <div>Sample</div>
        );
    }
}

MyView.propTypes = {
  url: React.PropTypes.string
}

MyView.defaultProps = {
  url: ''
}
```

Check [the official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#default-prop-values) for more information.

Comment: This does not work for TypeScript. `propTypes` and `defaultProps` cannot be "seen" by the compiler.